# How to select the last word in a string

Tags: mysql

I have used

```
SELECT
    SUBST(field_name, 1, Locate('',field_name)) AS first_word
      FROM
    table_name
```

and it works for the first word so I tried using last_word but still get the first word so I guess there must be a differet way??

Answer (score 11):

`Select SUBSTRING_INDEX(field_name,' ',-1)`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Answer (score 1):

Well, you probably could do:

```
SELECT REVERSE( SUBST( REVERSE( field_name ), 1, LOCATE( ' ', REVERSE( field_name )))
```

This likely won't work if your field has trailing spaces or is a single word.